# Angular2 fonts in my css file can't load

Tags: css, angular, fonts, loader

I am writing component with css files, but it seems like the fonts file can't be included.

Below is my code:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    pipes: [TranslatePipe],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    styleUrls: ['./app.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './app.html'
})
```

I write my webpack config :

```json
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
    },
    {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
    },
    {
        test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
    }
```

While in my app.css I have some fonts included:

```css
src:url(./fonts/nucleo-mini.eot) format("embedded-opentype");
src:url(./fonts/nucleo-mini.woff2) format("woff2");
src:url(./fonts/nucleo-mini.woff) format("woff");
src:url(./fonts/nucleo-mini.ttf) format("truetype");
src:url(./fonts/nucleo-mini.svg) format("svg");
```

but it's not working:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.css
Module build failed: /Users/liushun/pxx/plat/src/app/fonts/nucleo-mini.eot:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :
```

I changed my css loaders to `['raw-loader', 'url-loader']`, the error has gone,but it inserts a script to my `<style>...</style>` tags, the page can't read it.

Can somebody help me?